# Run unknown number of activity functions from Durable Function

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using .NET Core 3.1

I have a list of files which I need to split into tranches

I want to run an activity function for each of these tranches

For example if I have say 100 filenames and I want to split them into tranches of 10, I will end up with 10 tranches

I want to execute my activity function against each tranche

As the number of tranches will vary I have to add them at run time

Each tranche is totally independent, i.e. they have no impact on each other

How can I use Durable Functions to run each tranche **in parallel**

My current code is below

When run against a simple list its fine, but here there are more tranches

This is because I am analyzing a folder with a lot of files in it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Functions
{
    public static class FunctionTestParallel
    {
        [FunctionName("FunctionTestParallel")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            string directoryPath = @"C:\temp\All Data 3 - Copy";
            string searchPattern = "*.*"; 

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
            var uniqueFiles = new List<string>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(file);
                if (hashSet.Contains(json) == false)
                {
                    uniqueFiles.Add(file);
                    hashSet.Add(json);
                }
            }
            
            var batchSize = 10;

            var tranches = BatchList(uniqueFiles, batchSize);

            var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            var enumerable = tranches.ToList();
            for (var index = 0; index < enumerable.Count(); index++)
            {
                var tranche = enumerable.ElementAt(index).ToList();
                var dto = new TrancheDataDto
                {
                    Number = index + 1,
                    Filenames = tranche
                };

                tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<string>("SayHello", dto));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var outputs = new List<string>();
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                outputs.Add(task.Result);
            }
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("SayHello")]
        public static async Task<string> SayHello([ActivityTrigger] TrancheDataDto dto, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Processing Tranche {dto.Number} with {dto.Filenames.Count} files");

            foreach (var filename in dto.Filenames)
            {

                log.LogInformation($"Processing file: {filename}");

                await Task.Delay(100);
            }

            return $"Processed Tranche {dto.Number}";
        }

        private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BatchList<T>(List<T> source, int batchSize)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += batchSize)
            {
                yield return source.Skip(i).Take(batchSize);
            }
        }


        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("FunctionTestParallel", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }

    public class TrancheDataDto
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public List<string> Filenames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the error (the same one as I have had all along)

[image]
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durable Functions are a great way to handle long-running and parallelizable workflows.
However, there are a few adjustments needed to your code to ensure that each tranche is processed in parallel and independently.

First, let's make sure your activity function is running asynchronously and returns a value. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve parallel processing of each tranche:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _2._0
{
    public class TrancheDataDto
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public List<string>? Filenames { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var uniqueFilenames = new List<string>
            {
                "myfile.txt", "yourfile.txt", "therefile.txt", /* ... */ "file100.txt"
            }; 
            var batchSize = 10;

            var tranches = BatchList(uniqueFilenames, batchSize);

            var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            for (var index = 0; index < tranches.Count(); index++)
            {
                var tranche = tranches.ElementAt(index).ToList();
                var dto = new TrancheDataDto
                {
                    Number = index + 1,
                    Filenames = tranche
                };

                tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<string>("SayHello", dto));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var outputs = new List<string>();
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                outputs.Add(task.Result);
            }
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(SayHello))]
        public static async Task<string> SayHello([ActivityTrigger] TrancheDataDto dto, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Processing Tranche {dto.Number} with {dto.Filenames.Count} files");

            foreach (var filename in dto.Filenames)
            {

                log.LogInformation($"Processing file: {filename}");

                await Task.Delay(100);
            }

            return $"Processed Tranche {dto.Number}";
        }
        private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BatchList<T>(List<T> source, int batchSize)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += batchSize)
            {
                yield return source.Skip(i).Take(batchSize);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this, please see my updated question where I think I have applied your approach.  I still get an error

Comment: Please refer to this
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=csharp)